# how can i get the details of a photo posted to facebook from instagram

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

I was trying to access the details(likes and comments) of the photos which are posted to facebook from instagram app.
I coulnd't find any way to get that.
how can i confirm that a photo is posted from instagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the facebook endpoint /me/instapp:take ?

I can at least get my photos... don't know about public pictures...

Answer (score 0):

Now I am able to get my instagram photos and others as well but the thing is we can't access anybody's instagram photo details for that we need to have access token of that user.